# Correlation failed when logging in for the second time after hitting the back button on the browser

Tags: oauth-2.0, .net-core, identityserver4

Ok, first question ever so be gentle. I've been struggling with this for about a week now and i am finally ready to accept defeat and ask for help.
Here's what is happening. I have an IdentityServer4 IDP, an API and an MVC Core Client. I am also interacting with 2 external OAuth2 IDPs provided by the business client. 
My problem scenario is this:

- The user logs in through my IDP(or potentially one of the external ones)
- Once the user is in the Mvc Client they hit the back button on their browser
- Which takes them back to the login page(whichever one they used)
- They reenter the credentials(login again)
- When redirected back(either to the MVC in the case of my IDP, or my IDP in the case of one of the external IDPs) i get RemoteFailure event with the message:[correlation failed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ogx3.png)

The problem seems, to me, to be the fact that you are trying to login when you are already logged in(or something). I've managed to deal with the case of logging in at my IDP, since the back button step takes the user to my Login action on the Controller(I then check if a user is authenticated and send them back to the MVC without showing them any page) but with the other two IDPs the back button does not hit any code in my IDP. Here are the config options for one of the OAuth2 external IDPs:

```
           .AddOAuth(AppSettings.ExternalProvidersSettings.LoginProviderName, ExternalProviders.LoginLabel, o =>
        {
            o.ClientId = "clientId";
            o.ClientSecret = "clientSecret";
            o.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            o.CallbackPath = PathString.FromUriComponent(AppSettings.ExternalProvidersSettings.LoginCallbackPath);
            o.AuthorizationEndpoint = AppSettings.ExternalProvidersSettings.LoginAuthorizationEndpoint;
            o.TokenEndpoint = AppSettings.ExternalProvidersSettings.LoginTokenEndpoint;
            o.Scope.Add("openid");
            o.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    //stuff
                },
                OnRemoteFailure = async context =>
                {
                    if (!HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect($"/home/error");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }
                }
            };
       }
```

The other one is the same. Since the error is exactly the same regardless of the IDP used, i am guessing it is not something native to OIDC but to OAuth middleware and the code(config options) they share, so i am not going to show the OIDC config on the MVC client(unless you insist). Given how simple the repro steps are i thought i would find an answer and explanation to my problem pretty fast, but i was not able to. Maybe the fix is trivial and i am just blind. Regardless of the situation, i would apreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your issue.
When the user goes back to the login screen after successfully logging in, 
it might well be that the query parameters in the URL of that page are no longer valid.
Don't think this is an issue specific to Identity Server.

You may read
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1251
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/720

Not sure how to prevent this from happening though.

Comment: It is indeed due to the URL not matching the cookies. Ive added some handler logic that tells the user to try again if this condition arises.

Comment: @mackie just to be clear, your're suggesting i add handler logic that tells the user to retry logging in. You haven't actually made code changes to the identityserver4 project(or anywhere else). It is a bit unclear from your comment.

Comment: You can add logic in the middleware event handlers. I check for particular exception types and messages and render a suitable UI which allows them to retry.